# VNC is connecting to the same user on different ports

Tags: rhel, vnc

I have a RHEL 7 server. I configured multi-user access for ten users using VNC.

Every user is assigned to a different port. It was working perfectly. Then I got a black screen problem. After trying many, I decided to delete all config files and recreate them.

The problem I have is when a port is assigned to the user, say 5905. It is connecting to the user who is assigned to 5910. Most of the users are connected to the screen of the user with port 5910. I've checked the `vncserver@:5. service` files.

What should I do?

Comment: Not using VNC for starters would be a good starting point. You are trying to use it for something it was not designed to do.

Comment: For creating multi user access what should i use instead of VNC?